# Django: Returning Json from view and parse value into d3.js

Tags: python, json, django, d3.js, django-templates

/anomaly/graphTest is the url to call my get_graph method in views.py I couldn't get the json from my method to return into my d3.json function. How can I do that? What I'm trying to do is something similiar to this https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-python-bolt to display stuff on a graph using d3.json. Is it because of the python version that is different which causes my application to work differently from the code sample? I have also printed out the value of graph[0]. it shows that graph[0] is undefined.

views.py

```
def get_graph(request):
    db = get_db()
    results = db.run("MATCH (m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a:Person) "
         "RETURN m.title as movie, collect(a.name) as cast ")
    nodes = []
    rels = []
    i = 0
    for record in results:
        nodes.append({"title": record["movie"], "label": "movie"})
        target = i
        i += 1
        for name in record['cast']:
            actor = {"title": name, "label": "actor"}
            try:
                source = nodes.index(actor)
            except ValueError:
                nodes.append(actor)
                source = i
                i += 1
            rels.append({"source": source, "target": target})
    return render(request, 'anomaly/index.html',{"nodes": nodes, "links": rels})
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var width = 800, height = 800;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-200).linkDistance(30).size([width, height]);

    var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
        .attr("width", "100%").attr("height", "100%")
        .attr("pointer-events", "all");

    d3.json("/anomaly/graphTEST", function(error, graph) {

        if (error) return;

        force.nodes(graph.nodes).links(graph.links).start();

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(graph.links).enter()
            .append("line").attr("class", "link");

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(graph.nodes).enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("class", function (d) { return "node "+d.label })
            .attr("r", 10)
            .call(force.drag);

        // html title attribute
        node.append("title")
            .text(function (d) { return d.title; })

        // force feed algo ticks
        force.on("tick", function() {
            link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

            node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Json sample that was returned upon calling the get_graph method

```
{"nodes": [{"title": "Apollo 13", "label": "movie"}, {"title": "Tom Hanks", "label": "actor"}, {"title": "Kevin Bacon", "label": "actor"}
```

Update 1:
I'm currently able to retrieve the data and has successfully parse into my javascript function, but when I print the value in the javascript function, it shows me weird symbol which i'm not expecting.

javascript weird json

```
[{&#39;title&#39;: &#39;Apollo 13&#39;, &#39;label&#39;: &#39;movie&#39;}, {&#39;title&#39;: &#39;Tom Hanks&#39;, &#39;label&#39;: &#39;actor&#39;}, {&#39;title&#39;: &#39;Kevin Bacon&#39;, &#39;label&#39;: &#39;actor&#39;},
```

Comment: Please move text above code... (tired of scrolling up and down more than once when reading a question.)

Comment: Good...Now modifiy your `view.py` script such that it is working **"minimally"**, we can reprodice your error, and produces a traceback error. Post the traceback below index.html if its a large error. Most of the time the last line tells you what goes wrong and where it goes wrong.

Comment: @ZF007 i have edited my post to add in the codes instead of pseudo code. It doesn't return any error. It returns me to a page with json instead of returning the value back to index.html. I have added the json sample that it returns too

Comment: If I understand you correctly you run first the python script... get data via the `g.neo4j_db = driver.session()` and then want to parse it to d3.json index.html script at the end of the python script, right? If so.. then your python script is still incomplete and the linkage can not be made as a solution yet! I'm not a json coder so.. but what I see its starts with gui like properties.

Comment: @ZF007 Its is a website and not a script, it gets data from the db and then return as a value which is then formatted into json and then returned as json. However I'm trying to return the json into the index.html and parse it into a javascript function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164567/discussion-between-zf007-and-django-newbie).